# How to get data from a database using FOREACH in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Please I have a health management system and trying to get data from the database using foreach. The return value is one array result instead of two. Kindly go through my code. I need assistance to display all results.

***Controller.php***

```
$result = \DB::table('patient_results')
        ->select('*')
        ->whereIn('test', $arraylistTable)
        ->where('patient_id', $id)
        ->where('specimen_id', $specimen_id)
        ->get();


        $testValue = $result->pluck('test'); //return values [ "KMS", "MLS"]
        
        foreach($testValue as $clinical_data) {

           return $Testdata = \DB::table('tests')
            ->select('*')
            ->where('test_name', $clinical_data)
            ->get();            
           // returns data for only "KMS" Instead of both. There exist a data for both "KMS", "MLS". How do I display them
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows one record because you have return statement in your loop.
It retuns back on the first execution.

**Solution**

- Combine all the records in an array and then return

**Better Solution**

- Apply Join of both the tables or write a Sub-Query. This will reduce your overhead of the Loop.

Comment: please this is the error am recieving ```Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array```

Answer (score 1):

`where` takes a single value. You're looking for [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses), which will use the array for the search. It translates to `where test_name IN ('KMS','MLS')`

```
->whereIn('test_name', $clinical_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$testValue = $result->pluck('test'); //return values [ "KMS", "MLS"]
$newArray = [];
array_push($testValue , $newArray);

   
        foreach($newArray as $clinical_data) {

           return $Testdata = \DB::table('tests')
            ->select('*')
            ->whereIn('$clinical_data', $newArray)
            ->get();            
           // returns data for only "KMS" Instead of both. There exist a data for both "KMS", "MLS". How do I display them
        }
```